# How do you process a sequence of Akka Stream Sources?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

We have a `Sink` that can handle events:

```
def parseEvent(): Sink[T, Future[akka.Done]] = {
  Sink.foreach[T] { event => {
    // Do stuff with the event
  }}
}
```

This works fine with a single `Source`:

```
val mySource: Source[T] = ...  
mySource.takeWhile( someCheck, true ).runWith(parseEvent)
```

How do you get it working if you instead have:

```
val mySources: Seq[Source[T]] = ...
```

All sources should run in parallel and all events should reach `parseEvent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the following lines should fit the bill:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{ Concat, Merge, Source }

def sourceFromSources[T](sources: Seq[Source[T, NotUsed]]): Source[T, NotUsed] =
  sources.size match {
    case s if s < 1 => Source.empty[T]
    case 1 => sources.head
    case 2 => sources.head.merge(sources(1))
    case _ => Source.combine(sources.head, sources(1), sources.drop(2): _*)(Merge(_))
  }
```

The merge strategy "merges multiple streams, taking elements as they arrive from the input streams" and chooses randomly if multiple streams have elements available.  Backpressure is propagated from the downstreams to the upstreams.

Comment: I lifted it from the docs for `Source.combine` (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/combine.html), so it's really just Akka Streams that's awesome :)

Comment: What about sources.reduce((s1,s2)=>Source.combine(s1,s2)(Merge(_)))? @antex